# Adjust thumbnail area to image and text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I'm using `thumbnail class` in my view, but I need to reduce the `thumbnail` area exactly to fit just my image and text, how can I do that? This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">               
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail thumbnailBorder" style="background-color:red">
                            <img src="~/LIGAppsForWebsite/@item" style="height:133px; width:213px;" alt="@temp">
                            @temp
                        </a>              
            </div>
</div>
```

This is what is happening now:
[image]

And I would like to get something like this even if `background-color:red` for `class:thumbnail` is set:
[image]

How can I do that?

**EDIT**

I don't want the cursor handle to display when I'm hovering above the red surface, I just want it to display when I'm hovering above the image and text

Comment: try object-fit ? https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/ or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">               
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail thumbnailBorder">
            <img src="~/LIGAppsForWebsite/@item" alt="@temp">
            <p>Image Text</p>
        </a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail {
    width: 213px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.thumbnail:hover {
    background-color:red;
}

.thumbnail img {
    width: 213px;
    height: 133px;
}

.thumbnail p {
    margin: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Demo: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/darioferrer/qvuwj5h7/)

Note: HTML5 [accepts nested tags](http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/) in anchor elements without breaking validation

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution, just adding `display:inline-block` to the tag that contains the `class="thumbnail"` will do it, `display:inline-block` means that the element will take just the [necessary area](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp) and not more...